# Finding total number of unique values in a multi indexed dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the given dataframe below. I want to know if for each index in X (i.e 1,2 and 3), the values in other index Y are same and total number of them. 
So for X index 1, i want to know what values are in Y which is a, b and c. And whether it is equal to Y's index values for 2 and 3. So here Y values for X index 1 is equal to Y values for X index 3 i.e they both have a,b and c, while for 3 is not same.

```
X     Y   
1    a         A
     b         B
     c         C
2    a         A
     b         B
3    a         A
     b         B
     c         D
```

Answer (score 0):

If maximum length of `Y` level has all possible unique values is possible use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
print (type(s))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (s.unstack())
Y  a  b    c
X           
1  A  B    C
2  A  B  NaN
3  A  B    D
```

And then remove rows with incomplete values, it means rows with missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df1 = s.unstack().dropna()
print (df1)
Y  a  b  c
X         
1  A  B  C
3  A  B  D

print (df1.columns.tolist())
['a', 'b', 'c']

print (len(df1))
2
```

Comment: printing columns.tolist() says  AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'. S is a dataframe actually.

Comment: @Azz - What is `print (s.columns)` ?